# Newbie, help makeing an object

Tags: c++, object, vector

I'm working on learning c++, I already know java, c# +++. So I thought it would be a walk in the park, but no!!
What I'm trying to do is make a simple object("test"), where I can add strings to the vector "data" through the add function, and then make some kind of print function that prints it. I've tried make something shown underneath, any input would be appreciated :)

```
Call:
test a;
a.add("blabla");
a.print();

test.h:
class test{
    vector<string>* data;
    std::string str;
public:
    test();
    void add(std::string t);
};

**test.cpp:**
test::test() {
data = new vector<string>;
}

void test::add(std::string t) {
data->pushback(t);
}

void test::print() {
cout << data[0];
}
```

Comment: First of all, lose the pointer and use the stack: `vector<string> data;`. It gets default-initialized, and you don't have to free the memory it uses. Second, error messages are nice, but I suppose you're getting one for using `pushback` instead of `push_back`.

Comment: +1 since i dont know why this was downvoted. This question is not well phrased but when you're first learning a langauge sometimes its hard to know WHAT to ask and that is 90% of your problem. Lets be patient and accepting of our less experienced users.

Comment: So what is the problem? A compilation error? Output is not as expected? Actually you need to make a real question.

Answer (score 2):

One of the fundamental thing that makes C++ different from Java and C# is that in C++ all classes are "value classes". The other is that dynamic memory is "manual".

From the second point descends the fact that every time you call `new`, you must think about who and when will call `delete`.

From the first point descends that `vector` and `string` behave as values, and that the dynamic memory required to handle their growing and shrinking is managed by the classes themselves. There is no need to allocate them dynamically.

You must also take care of the headers where classes are declared (that must be `#include`d where used) and of the namespaces that contains the declaration you use (either by declare a `using` or by callign them explicitly).

The following code does (in a single file) what you wanted.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    void add(std::string t);
    void print() const;
private:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> data_t;
    data_t data;
};

void test::add(std::string t)
{ data.push_back(t); }

void test::print() const
{
    for(data_t::size_type i=0; i<data.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test a;
    a.add("first");
    a.add("second");
    a.add("third");
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

There are more `canonical` ways to handle printing (by parametrising the output stream and making a << operator overload that treats an "a" as another ordinary value).
But right now, compare this code (that the most similar to your one) with yours and find out what's not just syntactically different.

EDIT

I don't know if you are using C++11 or not...
There are two possible enhancement, here:

If stuck to C++03,

`void add(sd::string t)` cand be better parametrised as

```
void add(const std::string& t)
//       ^^^^^            ^
```

If using C++11, since you don't need `t` anymore after giving it to push_back,

```
void test::add(std::string t)
{ data.push_back(std::move(t)); }
```

and in this case don't use `const&`.

Comment: I'd say let's not overwhelm the new C++ programmer with all kinds of canonical stuff. What he's trying to do can easily be implemented in code that looks almost the same as Java.

Comment: Yes, but ... that's not C++.

If we use a pointer and new / delete we have to decide what to do with copy, move and assign (do we have to share the data between different objects or not? Do we have to admit new copy to be created and when and how?) Java don't impose this dilemma: classes are all by reference (and hence shared). C# lets you decide at the very beginning (it is a class or a struct: no half-way).
Staying away of this problems makes you Jav-ize C++ (and introduce memory leaks, since C++ wont manage them). But if you want a C++ that looks like Java, IMHO, you had better to use Java.

Comment: Wow that is amazing feedback. PS I don’t want it to be easy, I want to learn it the right way (no memory leaks)

I went with this solution, and now it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to include test.h in the file with your main method?

Also, you either need to use `std::cout` or have the line `using namespace std;` in your code.

In addtion, the push-back method for vector is `push_back()`, not `pushback()`.

Finally, since you're using the `new` keyword in your constructor, you'll need a destructor as well that would look something like this:

```
test::~test()
{
    delete data;
}
```

This is a very important thing to remember when you are doing C++ programming as opposed to Java or C#.  C++ implementations do not automatically garbage collect, so you need to take care of releasing your allocated memory on your own.

EDIT:

Also, one of the answers below points out another issue. You forgot to dereference the vector pointer before indexing into it.  You need to print out `(*data)[0]`.  Moral of the story is, it would definitely be easier and better if you made data a `vector` rather than a pointer to `vector`.

Comment: And of course the copy/move constructor and assignment operator. It just gets a lot worse when you're using pointers when you shouldn't be.

Comment: @chris true, but that's probably not going to cause a problem considering this is just a test program. I guess you're right, though. It's unlikely that the memory leak will cause any real problems either.

Comment: But it will in the future, and is also a very good habit to get into. One of the best things that can be done for Java programmers coming to C++ is defer the use of pointers to when they actually need them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to de-reference the vector pointer in test::print

```
void test::print() {
    cout << (*data)[0];
}
```

*Also it is important to remember to delete objects created with `new`